# Calling an existing variable dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic

I have a java program which uses multiple HashMaps, one for each "category" of order made in an hypothetical restaurant.

I need to do some processing and output text to a file. However, I have gone the "bad" way and simply wrote the code six times, calling a different hashmap in each of the times.

I cannot leave exact demo code as this will be delivered as a project and as such could be found by random plagiarism finders, and mistakenly marked as plagiarism since it'd be a huge chunk of code. However, the following should sort of illustrate the problem.

```
DoSomething(These);
DoSomething(All);
DoSomething(Have);
DoSomething(Completely);
DoSomething(Different);
DoSomething(Names);
```

Now instead of "DoSomething", imagine having 20 lines of code, and for each 20 lines I use one specific HashMap.

I can't exactly populate an array and make it use the data from the Array, as it'll attempt to use Strings instead of the HashMap (calling DoSomething("These") instead of DoSomething(These)).

Is there any way to call the HashMaps dynamically, so that I can shorten all this into just one single loop that does the same thing for each of the HashMaps?

Comment: If the same operations are indeed being performed on all of the HashMaps then why not just create an array of HashMap[] that contains all of them and loop through that?

Comment: Your question seems to answer your problem.  Turn the 20 lines into a method with a map parameter.

Comment: Or, instead of doing the same operation 6 time for 6 different HashMaps, maybe mark the data in the HashMap as to what phases they need to be processed in, then you can loop once and do the relevant parts once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a couple hashmaps, lets say:

```
HashMap<String, String> aMap;
HashMap<String, String> anotherMap;
```

You could then populate a new ArrayList with these, like so:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> myMaps = new ArrayList<>();
myMaps.add(aMap);
myMaps.add(anotherMap);
```

With this, you can iterate through your maps using an enhanced for loop:

```
for (HashMap map : myMaps) {
    //code goes here
}
```

A benefit here is that your list is dymanically sized, therefore you can add and remove hashmaps from it as you please.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Using the HashMap this way allowed me to do an HashMap<HashMap<String, Integer>, String>, keeping a string associated with each HashMap for further data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's time to do some **refactoring**.

- The 6 "different" methods should be turned into one which takes a
  hashmap as parameter. As that is the only difference they have.
- Also it sounds like you should use some sort of collection for
  your hashmaps so you can iterate them - and use the one method you have created on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If every chunk of your code is so similar, an IDE like eclipse can easily recognize it and `refactor` it to 6 calls to "DoSomething" with a Map parameter.

If you have not such an IDE... do the same by hand, it is not that hard and will pay off (you actually **don't want** to maintain that mess and fix your errors or make your times x6 times through your code)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure based on your question what the DoSomething-method is supposed to do though, but I understood it as if it is supposed to return a certain HashMap depending on a certain order category that is provided as a String. In this case you could just make a HashMap of HashMap, with a String key for the first HashMap. Depending on the Sting key provided you would then obtain the corresponding HashMap.